# create table operator does not use correct mode for table columns

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, schema, directed-acyclic-graphs, mode

As part of a DAG in Airflow, I'm using a task with a BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator to create a new, empty table, and I'm passing the table's schema in the 'schema_fields' argument, as a Python variable that contains the schema as a list.  The mode of some columns in the schema is 'REQUIRED'
The DAG runs OK and the table is indeed created, but when I check it in BigQuery, all columns in the table have their mode set to 'NULLABLE' - the 'REQUIRED' mode has been ignored for the columns that should have it.

```
    create_table = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator( 
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED,
    task_id="create_table", 
    dataset_id = 'my_dataset', 
    table_id= "my_table", 
    project_id = 'my_project', 
    schema_fields= my_table_schema, 
    exists_ok=True
    )
```

My schema looks like this:

```
    my_table_schema =  [
  {
    "name": "ID_NO",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "REQUIRED"    
  },
  {
    "name": "PROD_NAME",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "DESC",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

So the table gets created with the columns from the schema above, but they've all got NULLABLE mode, even the ID_NO column.

Why is the mode in the schema being replaced by NULLABLE?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code setup and it is working fine for me. This might be some transient issue, do check if you're using the correct dag file in the Airflow environment.

Here is what I tried:

```
with models.DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule="@once",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example", "bigquery"],
) as dag:
    createtable1 = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator( 
    task_id='createtable', 
    dataset_id = 'my-dataset', 
    table_id= 'mytablecomposer', 
    project_id = 'my-project', 
    schema_fields= [{"name": "ID_NO","type": "INTEGER","mode": "REQUIRED" },{"name":"PROD_NAME","mode": "NULLABLE","type": "STRING"},{"name": "DESC","mode": "NULLABLE","type": "STRING" }], 
    exists_ok=True
    )
```

BigQuery Table:

[image]